# Ruby's array.sample() equivalent for lisp

Tags: faces

I want to write a method that returns a random (predefined) face

In ruby I would do,

```
def random_face
 [ :my-face-01, :my-face-02, :my-face-03 ].sample(1).first
end
```

How can I do it in elisp?

Comment: Check [this post](http://nullprogram.com/blog/2009/07/03/) that defines a function to pick a random element from a list. Quite simple.

Comment: You aren't asking for the equivalent of sample, but rather the equivalent of generating a random index. This is far easier than picking multiple items from a bag.